# How to set the maximal size of BLOB column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I want to set the maximal size of a BLOB column to be up to 900KB.
Is there a way similar to the syntax of the other String Data types - for example

```
c CHAR(7),
vc VARCHAR(50),
pic BLOB (???)
```

to do this?

Answer (score 5):

From the [storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) section of the manual, the max size of the following fields:

```
TINYBLOB   : L < 2^8  =           256 Bytes
BLOB       : L < 2^16 =        65,536 Bytes
MEDIUMBLOB : L < 2^24 =    16,777,216 Bytes
LONGBLOB   : L < 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 Bytes
```

In order to store 900KB, you would need to use a `MEDIUMBLOB` at the very minimum.

As far as I know, you can not specify your own size for the field.

Answer (score -2):

With our IBM Database (AS400), it is possible to provide a size to a Blob field.

```
fieldName Blob(size in bytes)
```

The maximum Size is then visible like any other length

Screenshot from DBvisualizer:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIZaC.png]